# How to insert an object into an array of object using electron-store

Tags: electron, config

I want to insert an object into an array which already has some object in it.

for example I have this object:

```
{"title": "Snow White", "page": 300}
```

and I want to add "book" with that object so that it would hold 3 object in it.

```
"bookmark": {
    "book": [
      {"title": "Cinderela", "page": 100},
      {"title": "Pinocchio", "page": 200}
    ]
}
```

How do I achieve this?

If I use this API:

```
.set(key, value)
```

I think it will remove the existing object and changed it with the new provided object.

Should I use:

```
.get(key, [defaultValue])
```

to get all objects in "book" and then add the new one along side the other objects before sending them back at once by using:

```
.set(object)
```

is there any simplest method than that?

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the get and set method to update the data

```
const book = store.get('bookmark.book');
const newBooks = [...(book || []), {"title": "Snow White", "page": 300}];
store.set('bookmark.book', newBooks);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you declare a object with bookmark and book as one of its property, then you can add any objects to this books array using push(), as below

```js
let obj = {
            bookmark: {
               book : []
            }
          }

obj.bookmark.book.push({"title": "Cinderela", "page": 100});
obj.bookmark.book.push({"title": "Pinocchio", "page": 200});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have added some more details. What I mean is the way I should do to add new object into config.json file using electron-store API